# calling an apex method from javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

```
function check(){
   var user = document.getElementById('pg:frm:nPB:ip').value;
   if(user == ''){
       alert('Please Enter noise Name before Proceeding.');
       return true;
   }
   else{
     noiseSearch();
     return true;
    }
 </script>
 <apex:commandButton value="Search" onclick="check();" 
                        action="{!noiseSearch}"  reRender="nPbt" />
```

controller

```
public class controller{
    public pageReference noiseSearch(){
         //logic
         return null;
    }
}
```

,i tired with about code,but my noisesearch() not called,i want to know why it is not called

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use actionfuntion here

> **[apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)**
>
> A component that provides support for invoking controller action methods directly from JavaScript code using
>   an AJAX request. An  component must be a child of
>   an  component.

So your button will be

```
<apex:commandButton value="Search" onclick="check();" reRender="nPbt" />
```

And your script function

```
  function check(){
    var user = document.getElementById('pg:frm:nPB:ip').value;
    if(user == ''){
        alert('Please Enter noise Name before Proceeding.');
        return true;
    }
    else
        noiseSearchAF();
        return true;
   }
```

And your action function will be

```
<apex:actionFunction action="{!noiseSearch}" name="noiseSearchAF" rerender="nPbt">
```

### Another way use Javascript remoting

[Check JavaScript Remoting Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_example.htm)

Comment: thanq,solved my problem